# Is it possible to query MongoDB by subfield object values?

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like this:

```
db.planet.insert({ 
    name: 'Earth',
    stuff: {
        'grass': 'green',
        'sky': 'blue',
        'sea': 'blue'
    }
})
db.planet.insert({ 
    name: 'Mars',
    stuff: {
        'dust': 'red',
        'sky': 'yellow'
    }
})
```

I want to find all planets that have at least some `blue` *stuff* (only earth in this case). How can I do that?

**Catch**: I tried solving this by using an array (instead of object) for *stuff* (`stuff: [ { k: 'grass', v: 'green'},... ]`) but I also need to be able to update (*upsert* to be exact) value of some *stuff*. For instance I must be able to do this:

```
db.planet.update({ name: 'Mars' }, {
    '$set': { 
        'stuff.canals': 'brown', 
        'stuff.dust': 'reddish' 
    } 
})
```

So, how can I find the planets with something `blue` on them? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the $or operator. The $or operator value should be an array, with the array containing conditions of which at least one must be true.

In your case, given the field names you have mentioned:

```
 db.planet.find($or:[
   {"stuff.sky":"blue"},
   {"stuff.grass":"blue"},
   {"stuff.sea":"blue"},
   {"stuff.dust":"blue"},
   {"stuff.canals":"blue")
 ])
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/
As there are a quite a number of different fields you want to query, you may want to keep an array of all these field names somewhere so you can generate the $or array programmatically.

I don't think there's a way to make the query without knowing the field names in advance. See  [mongodb query without field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901151/mongodb-query-without-field-name) .

Comment: Meryn, thanks! Since I don't know the field names your solution is not suitable for my case, but there is an acceptable solution at the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901151/mongodb-query-without-field-name). Not sure how I missed that question. :)