# How to find MongoDB documents with value only?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
{
    "name"    : "Apple",
    "partner" : "Samsung-Sony" 
}
{
    "name"    : "Samsung",
    "partner" : "Google-LG"
}
{
    "name"    : "McDonald",
    "partner" : "Burgerking"
}
```

If I have above like data structure, How can I find documents which has `Samsung` value? In this example, it should be return

```
{
    "name"    : "Apple",
    "partner" : "Samsung-Sony" 
}
{
    "name"    : "Samsung",
    "partner" : "Google-LG"
}
```

Because first of above, it has `Samsung` in `partner` filed name, and second, it has `Samsung` in `name` field. I want to find documents without specific field name. How to find it?

I red this([mongodb query without field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901151/mongodb-query-without-field-name)) question, but this is 7 years old question so I write this.

Comment: Dumb thought, but do you need truly dynamic field names, or could you just `$or` two queries together?

Comment: Juntae did you have a chance to look at my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes, Thanks a lot, I look your answer but it seems like should drop database and create again, because of `createIndex`. right? I am finding simple way, of course your way is simple but I can implemented it db design level. and @mickl 's answer he manually code field name. anyway thanks a lot I should think about that again.

Comment: @Juntae no need to drop database, you can create the index to an existing collection. With text index we have score, and it is easier to query, because no need to add all fields to the query

Comment: And more importantly text search will be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) by creating a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

Let's say you have this sample products schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  partner: String
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

And these documents in products collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e67e98e41b119430816c779"),
    "name" : "McDonald",
    "partner" : "Burgerking"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e67e98241b119430816c778"),
    "name" : "Samsung",
    "partner" : "Google-LG"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e67e97541b119430816c777"),
    "name" : "Apple",
    "partner" : "Samsung-Sony"
}
```

First we create an index on the fields we want to search at products collection using mongodb shell or some gui like MongoDB Atlas.

```js
db.products.createIndex(
   {
     name: "text",
     partner: "text"
   }
 )
```

Now we can search by a term like this:

```js
const Product = require("../models/product"); 

router.get("/products", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Product.find(
    { $text: { $search: req.query.term } },
    { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
  ).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } });

  res.send(result);
});
```

When we send a search term in the querystring like this: `http://.../products?term=Samsung`

The result will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e67e98241b119430816c778",
        "name": "Samsung",
        "partner": "Google-LG",
        "__v": 0,
        "score": 1.1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e67e97541b119430816c777",
        "name": "Apple",
        "partner": "Samsung-Sony",
        "__v": 0,
        "score": 0.75
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/index.html) to handle the "contains" part and it should be used as part of [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html):

```
{ $expr: { $or: [ { $ne: [ { $indexOfBytes: [ "$partner", "Samsung" ] }, -1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$name", "Samsung" ] } ] } }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5b3JRI7oMCT)