# Get the keys corresponding to a value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document inside my Mongodb collection, something like this :

```
{
 "a": "Bahrain",
 "b": "Bahrain",
 "c": "Bahrain",
 "d": "Oman",
 "e": "Oman",
 "f": "Oman"
}
```

What I want is to get the keys corresponding to a value i.e query by the values.

Eg. For value Bahrain, I want to get `{"a","b","c"}` as the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb query without field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901151/mongodb-query-without-field-name)

Comment: your expected output `{"a","b","c"}` is not a valid json format, please provide valid format.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to transform the `$$ROOT` variable to an array. then filter it according to the condition you want, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: docId }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      fieldKeys: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
              },
              as: "datum",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$datum.v",
                  "Bahrain"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "key",
          in: "$$key.k"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rjADnx_Rgf2)